# Importing Datetimes into Excel

Tags: pandas, openpyxl, nsepy

Error in `option.py` below, at line (near the end):

```
ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value=c
```

The error is:

```
raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))

ValueError: Cannot convert [Date

2014-12-01    8555.9

Name: Close, dtype: float64] to Excel
```

Here is the file `option.py`:

```
#importing the necessary packages
import numpy
from nsepy import get_history 
import datetime
from nsepy.derivatives import get_expiry_date
import openpyxl

#opening the excel sheet
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('/home/arvind/summer_sweta/financial_math/computation/option.xlsx') 
ws=wb.active

#to get the expiry date of the particular year and month when the option will expire 
xyear = int(input('Enter the expiry year(e.g. 2013)'))
xmonth = int(input('Enter the expiry month(e.g. 6,12)'))  
expiry=get_expiry_date(year=xyear,month=xmonth) 

#we want the index option price data where days of maturity will be between 40 and 60
sdate =expiry-(datetime.timedelta(days=60)) 
edate =expiry-(datetime.timedelta(days=40))     

#index for the rows of the excell sheet
i=1

#loop where we find data for all the possible days  
while(sdate!=edate):     
#underlying index price data                            
    nifty_price = get_history(symbol="NIFTY 50",
    start=sdate,
    end=sdate,
    index=True)

#condition to check if data is empty    
    if (nifty_price.empty):             
        sdate += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        continue

#to get index option price data 
    nifty_opn = get_history(symbol="NIFTY",
    start=sdate,
    end=sdate,
    index=True,
    option_type='CE',
    strike_price=int(numpy.round(nifty_price.get('Close'),-2)), #to round off the strike price to the nearest hundred
    expiry_date=expiry)         

    if (nifty_opn.empty):
        sdate += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        continue


    if (int(nifty_opn.get('Number of Contracts'))): #we want the data only of days when the option was traded

#we are only collecting the relevant information we need
        symbol=nifty_opn.get('Symbol')
        date=nifty_price.get('Date')
        close=nifty_price.get('Close')
        expiry=nifty_opn.get('Expiry')
        strike_price=nifty_opn.get('Strike Price')
        settle_price=nifty_opn.get('Settle Price')
        contracts_no=nifty_opn.get('Number of Contracts')    
        data= [symbol,date,close,expiry, strike_price,settle_price,
contracts_no]

        j=1
        for c in data:
            ws.cell(row=i,column=j).value=c
            j +=1
            i +=1
        sdate += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
#saving the information to the excel
wb.save('option.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `nsepy.derivatives` nor `openpyxl`, so, I cannot validate or confirm.  But the error points you most of the way there:

## Understanding your error

The proper Python [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object that you're likely getting from `get_expiry_date` in the line `expiry=get_expiry_date(year=xyear,month=xmonth)` cannot fully/properly be understood within Excel.

You can look deeper within the `openpyxl` code for how dates are managed, but barring that, simply convert your `datetime` object to a string in the format you want before pushing it out to Excel.

## Solution

Right after `for c in data:`, you can add:

```
if isinstance(c, datetime.datetime):
    d = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

This will convert `d` into a string in a format something like `"2018-06-30"` (year, month, day).  You can change it to whatever format you like... I prefer the Asian style, as given here, since it's fully unambiguous.

PS.  I severely edited your question to make it more manageable.  The easier the question is to read/understand, the more/better the responses you'll get.

Comment: Thank you so much for editing the question, it is much more understandable now. Since this is my first time posting question on stackoverflow, I will keep it in mind from the next time.

Comment: Yes, your solution will definitely work but before that I found another mistake in my code which I have to fix.See the link                                                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120272/how-to-get-relevant-data-say-only-the-underlying-price-from-the-get-history-fu

Comment: If it helped, please accept the answer and vote it up.  Thanks!

Comment: Since I do not have the required number of  reputations, my up-vote is recorded but not publicly shown.